# "Error Sending message" in firebase console

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I am trying to implement push notifications for an iOS app in swift, when I try to send a notification through firebase console it gives me "error sending message", what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was because I have 2 apps in the same project but was trying to send to just one of them, you must send to all of you projects